# Deletion of my user account from Histoy.SE is not working

Tags: feature-request

Some days ago I tried to delete my History.SE account by using the instructions given (edit the about field to "please delete me" and posting the request here), but my meta-post was deleted and nothing happened, not even I get a confirmation email.

Could you confirm that my History.SE account will be deleted and tell me when?

Thank you.

Comment: Aww Carlo, say it ain't so :( You are one of the more colorful personalities on stackexchange, your departure will be a loss.

Comment: What Meta post, and why would you even post on Meta in the first place? If you really want to go through with this all you need to do is go to [help center - contact us](http://history.stackexchange.com/contact) and pick "I need to delete my user profile" in the "What can we help you with?" field.

Comment: @YannisRizos Carlo_R. is a big proponent of asking things on meta. Right Carlo_R.? all other questions aside why do you feel the need to leave the site?

Comment: by the way Carlo_R. if you REALLY want to remove your profile from the site, it will take a few days. in my experience around 2 or three days and you should be deleted. sorry to see you go buddy.

Comment: @Carlo_R I thought I already deleted your History.SE account at your request. I'm not sure why I didn't work, but I'll look into it.

Comment: @ihtk, if so, perhaps deletion didn't work because when you attempeted deleting me I had a bounty opened. However, my bounty is now expired and you may delete me without any problem.

Comment: Thanks to all kind people that supported me in this thread, and adieu!

Comment: @franklin, thank you, I'm pleased hearing these things from you; but policies are not still well defined here and so there is no reason to stay further. However in the future, when and if some mods will be went away (except T.E.D. who is good) I can return. My suggestion to this community is electing Yannis Rizos as head mod and some other user like tomau, felix, kmlawson, voictus, drux as mods. Changing mods is absolutely need at this point (2,4 questions/day!) Thank you again.

Comment: @Yannis, even though we had some misunderstandings in the past, after careful consideration I realized that you would be an excellent moderator. In fact, contrary to what I have argued often, your comments and your answers to my questons have been always appropriate and in the spirit of SE philosophy. Adieu.

Comment: @Carlo_R. I think your account keeps getting recreated because you keep posting things. So, I would say stop posting things, unless you want to stay on the site in which case we are happy to have you here!